# Titanium.Facebook errDomain error 10000

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, titanium

I am developping an iPhone app with appcelerator's Titanium studio. My app uses the Facebook module It has the permissions read feed and publish feed and it authorizes properly but when I try to publish something to the user's feed or read the feed I get the error "errDomain error 10000" 95% of the time, it works correctly every 2 days so I know my requests are valid. I can't find any solution to this problem, I have tried loggin out and back in it doesn't work :( So could you please help me?

This is my code:

```
Titanium.Facebook.requestWithGraphPath('me/feed', {message: "Trying out FB Graph API and it's NOT fun at all!"}, "POST", function(e) {
if (e.success) 
{
    alert("Success!  From FB: " + e.result);
} 
else 
{
    if (e.error) 
    {
        alert(e.error);
    } 
    else 
    {
        alert("Unkown result");
    }
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`Titanium.Facebook` is deprecated  see here

http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/api/Modules.Facebook

and try to access graph path using a valid access token

```
fb.requestWithGraphPath('me/feed?access_token=YOUR_APP_ACCESS_TOKEN' , {message: "your message"}, 'POST', if (e.success) 
{
    alert("Success!  From FB: " + e.result);
} 
else 
{
    if (e.error) 
    {
        alert(e.error);
    } 
    else 
    {
        alert("Unkown result");
    }
}
});
```